# Propositional Logics

Tags: propositional-calculus

Any one that can work out the details that are missing from this:

(¬B1 ∧¬¬B2 ∧¬B2)∨(¬¬B1 ∧¬B2 ∧¬B2)∨(¬¬B1 ∧¬¬B2 ∧B2)

to this:

(B1 ∧ ¬B2) ∨ (B1 ∧ B2)

I know that they are of course using Double Negation law - but i don't get it afterwards. Is it the ditributivity?

Anyone that can give me some help? I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the first parenthesized group is a contradiction (B2 and not B2). Also, you can simplify “B2 and B2” to just B2.